# Avoiding gaps in datetime intervals with CTE and start and end datetimes

Tags: t-sql, date, common-table-expression, overlapping

For some reason I am seeing gaps in my time intervals using this query. I have gotten it to work when just using basic data. However, when joining my tables and specifying a WHERE clause, I see gaps in my time interval. I also need to incorporate the S.SessionEndTime in my intervals to find a count of records where there is overlap with a given 1 minute interval between the ResponseTime and SessionEndTime.

Here is the query I am using. By using a derived table, I get a MAX per hour based on the COUNT for 1 minute intervals.

```
    DECLARE @start_date     DATETIME
DECLARE @end_date       DATETIME
DECLARE @interval TIME

SET @start_date = '08/01/2012'
SET @end_date = '08/01/2012 12:00:00'
SET @interval = '00:01:00.00';

    WITH TimeWindowsCTE AS 
    ( 
        SELECT 
            @start_date AS WindowStart, @start_date + @interval AS WindowEnd 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 
            SW.WindowStart + @Interval, SW.WindowEnd + @interval 
        FROM 
            TimeWindowsCTE AS SW 
        WHERE 
            SW.WindowEnd < @end_date 
    ) 
    SELECT 
        DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, CONVERT(datetime, '19000101', 112), t1.WindowStart), CONVERT(datetime, '19000101', 112)) WindowStart, 
        MAX([Sessions]) [Sessions]
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            SW.WindowStart, COUNT(*) [Sessions] 
        FROM 
            TimeWindowsCTE AS SW 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN SessionDetails AS S ON SW.WindowStart <= S.ResponseTime and S.ResponseTime < SW.WindowEnd
            --I need to introduce the S.SessionEndTime into the JOIN so I can count the number of records that 
            --fall within the interval
            LEFT OUTER JOIN VoipDetails V on S.SessionIdTime = V.SessionIdTime and S.SessionIdSeq = V.SessionIdSeq                      
            WHERE V.ToGatewayId IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY 
            SW.WindowStart
    ) t1
    GROUP BY 
        DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, CONVERT(datetime, '19000101', 112), t1.WindowStart), CONVERT(datetime, '19000101', 112))
    ORDER BY 
        DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, CONVERT(datetime, '19000101', 112), t1.WindowStart), CONVERT(datetime, '19000101', 112))
    OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```

Here is the output that I'm getting

```
Date                      Sessions
2012-08-01 00:00:00.000   5
2012-08-01 01:00:00.000   3
2012-08-01 02:00:00.000   2
2012-08-01 03:00:00.000   2
2012-08-01 05:00:00.000   1
2012-08-01 06:00:00.000   2
2012-08-01 07:00:00.000   3
2012-08-01 08:00:00.000   2
2012-08-01 09:00:00.000   2
2012-08-01 10:00:00.000   1
```

I need a 0 for the time period 04:00:00. What I'm trying to accomplish is to determine how many concurrent sessions were occurring during that given hour, not how many sessions at the top of the hour. This is where the overlapping comes into play. If a call was iniatated at 8:56 am and ended at 9:26am, there should be at least 1 call in the 8am hour and 1 call in the 9am hour. Then based on the number of concurrent sessions for every hour in the day, I find the MAX for a given day and then use that in my report.

This is the basic structure of the data:

```
insert into @Sessions ( SessionIdSeq, ResponseTime, SessionEndTime ) values 
    (1, '20120901 00:00:00', '20120901 05:59:59' ), -- Several hours in a single session. 
    (1, '20120901 01:01:00', '20120901 01:01:30' ), -- An assortment of overlapping ... 
    (1, '20120901 01:02:00', '20120901 01:03:30' ), -- ... sessions during a single hour. 
    (1, '20120901 00:00:05.077', '20120901 00:04:02.280' ),
    (1, '20120901 00:00:14.687', '20120901 00:06:05.947' ),
    (1, '20120901 00:00:17.857', '20120901 00:07:34.757' ),
    (1, '20120901 00:00:25.843', '20120901 00:07:38.720' ),
    (1, '20120901 00:00:29.427', '20120901 00:01:58.180' ),
    (1, '20120901 00:00:31.853', '20120901 00:05:10.733' ),
    (1, '20120901 00:00:40.693', '20120901 00:00:44.237' ),
    (1, '20120901 00:00:58.773', '20120901 00:06:14.667' ),
    (1, '20120901 00:00:59.457', '20120901 00:01:01.310' ),
    (1, '20120901 00:01:16.390', '20120901 00:11:18.383' )
```

Comment: Well, the CTE looks familiar.  Can you show an example of the input and the output with an indication of what appears to be wrong?  And what you expect the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses to do.

Comment: Your various conversions appear to be designed to determine the "top of the hour" from a date/time.  Putting that into a clearly named function would make the code a lot easier to interpret.  I'd also avoid the conversions to and from text and go with something more like: `declare @Now as DateTime = GetDate(); select @Now as 'Now', DateAdd( hour, DatePart( hour, @Now ), Cast( Cast( @Now as Date ) as DateTime ) ) as 'Top Of The Hour'`.

Comment: Added the output I'm getting and what I want to get out of it. Thanks HABO!

Comment: Request For Clarification: Are you looking for (A) the maximum number of **concurrent** sessions in each hour, or (B) the **total number** of sessions that were active in each hour?  For example, if one long session starts at 8:00:00 and ends at 10:30:00, and 42 brief sessions start at 9:nn:05 and end at 9:nn:20 (where nn is 01 through 42), then method (A) returns 8:00 1, 9:00 2, 10:00 1.  Method (B) would return 8:00 1, 9:00 43, 10:00 1.

Comment: Looking for the maximum number of concurrent sessions in each hour. This involves a license issue and it revolves around concurrent sessions. I have two reports, one report with maximum concurrent sessions for the entire day with drilldown to the second report with # of concurrent sessions for each hour in that day

Comment: Did the second part of the answer help?  It's a more interesting little algorithm and I had the bad feeling that it was really what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, lacking a clarification here is some TSQL that computes both:
- the total number of sessions active in each hour and
- the maximum number of concurrent sessions active in each hour.

**EDIT**: The sample data from the updated question has been used, the output of the last query which shows concurrent sessions now includes the session ids, and a bug in the prior optimization was corrected which *greatly* improves performance.

**NB**: These queries work best when the `SessionId` values vary from row to row.  Using a value of `1` for all rows will cause disappointing results.  Hence the `IDENTITY` property on the `SessionId` column.

```
-- Parameters.
declare @Start as DateTime = '20120901 00:00:00'
declare @End as DateTime = '20120901 12:00:00'
declare @Interval as Time = '01:00:00.00' -- One hour.
select @Start as [Start], @End as [End], @Interval as [Interval]

-- Sample data.
declare @Sessions as Table ( SessionId Int Identity, SessionStart DateTime, SessionEnd DateTime )
insert into @Sessions ( SessionStart, SessionEnd ) values
  ( '20120901 00:00:00', '20120901 05:59:59' ), -- Several hours in a single session.
  ( '20120901 01:01:00', '20120901 01:01:30' ), -- An assortment of overlapping ... 
  ( '20120901 01:02:00', '20120901 01:03:30' ), -- ... sessions during a single hour. 
  ( '20120901 00:00:05.077', '20120901 00:04:02.280' ),
  ( '20120901 00:00:14.687', '20120901 00:06:05.947' ),
  ( '20120901 00:00:17.857', '20120901 00:07:34.757' ),
  ( '20120901 00:00:25.843', '20120901 00:07:38.720' ),
  ( '20120901 00:00:29.427', '20120901 00:01:58.180' ),
  ( '20120901 00:00:31.853', '20120901 00:05:10.733' ),
  ( '20120901 00:00:40.693', '20120901 00:00:44.237' ),
  ( '20120901 00:00:58.773', '20120901 00:06:14.667' ),
  ( '20120901 00:00:59.457', '20120901 00:01:01.310' ),
  ( '20120901 00:01:16.390', '20120901 00:11:18.383' )
select * from @Sessions 

-- Summary of sessions active at any time during each hour. 
; with SampleWindows as ( 
  select @Start as WindowStart, @Start + @Interval as WindowEnd 
  union all 
  select SW.WindowStart + @Interval, SW.WindowEnd + @Interval 
    from SampleWindows as SW 
    where SW.WindowEnd < @End 
  ) 
  select SW.WindowStart, Count( S.SessionStart ) as [Sessions] 
    from SampleWindows as SW left outer join 
      @Sessions as S on SW.WindowStart <= S.SessionEnd and S.SessionStart < SW.WindowEnd 
    group by SW.WindowStart 

-- Summary of maximum concurrent sessions active during each hour. 
; with SampleWindows as ( 
  select 1 as SampleWindowId, @Start as WindowStart, @Start + @Interval as WindowEnd 
  union all 
  select SW.SampleWindowId + 1, SW.WindowStart + @Interval, SW.WindowEnd + @Interval 
    from SampleWindows as SW 
    where SW.WindowEnd < @End 
  ), 
  ActiveSessionsDuringWindow as ( 
  select SW.SampleWindowId, SW.WindowStart, SW.WindowEnd, S.SessionId, S.SessionStart, S.SessionEnd, 
    -- A "pane" is the more restrictive of the window and the session start/end times. 
    case when SW.WindowStart <= S.SessionStart then S.SessionStart else SW.WindowStart end as PaneStart, 
    case when SW.WindowEnd >= S.SessionEnd then S.SessionEnd else SW.WindowEnd end as PaneEnd
    from SampleWindows as SW left outer join 
      @Sessions as S on SW.WindowStart <= S.SessionEnd and S.SessionStart < SW.WindowEnd 
  ), 
  ConcurrentSearch as ( 
  select SampleWindowId, WindowStart, WindowEnd, SessionId, SessionStart, SessionEnd, PaneStart, PaneEnd, 
    Cast( '|' + Right( Replicate( '0', 3 ) + Cast( SessionId as VarChar(4) ), 4 ) + '|' as VarChar(1024) ) as SessionIds, 
    Cast( case when SessionId is NULL then 0 else 1 end as Int ) as Sessions 
    from ActiveSessionsDuringWindow 
  union all 
  select CS.SampleWindowId, CS.WindowStart, CS.WindowEnd, ASDW.SessionId, CS.SessionStart, CS.SessionEnd, 
    case when CS.PaneStart <= ASDW.PaneStart then ASDW.PaneStart else CS.PaneStart end as PaneStart, 
    case when CS.PaneEnd >= ASDW.PaneEnd then ASDW.PaneEnd else CS.PaneEnd end as PaneEnd, 
    Cast( CS.SessionIds + Right( Replicate( '0', 3 ) + Cast( ASDW.SessionId as VarChar(4) ), 4 ) + '|' as VarChar(1024) ), 
    CS.Sessions + 1 
    from ConcurrentSearch as CS inner join 
      ActiveSessionsDuringWindow as ASDW on ASDW.SampleWindowId = CS.SampleWindowId and 
        -- We haven't visited this session along this path. 
        CS.SessionId < ASDW.SessionId and -- EDIT: Reduce the size of the search tree. 
        CharIndex( '|' + Right( Replicate( '0', 3 ) + Cast( ASDW.SessionId as VarChar(4) ), 4 ) + '|', CS.SessionIds ) = 0 and 
        -- The session's pane overlaps the concurrent search pane. 
        CS.PaneStart <= ASDW.PaneEnd and ASDW.PaneStart <= CS.PaneEnd 
  )
  select WindowStart, Max( Sessions ) as Sessions,
    ( select top 1 SessionIds from ConcurrentSearch where Sessions = Max( CS.Sessions ) ) as SessionIds
    from ConcurrentSearch as CS
    group by WindowStart
```

Following is a variation on the last query which does not use row id values from the `@Sessions` table.  Instead it uses `Row_Number()` to assign suitable values for the duration of the query.  This also changes the assumption that the `SessionId` values do not exceed four digits to an assumption that there are not more than 9,999 sessions active within any given hour.

```
-- Summary of maximum concurrent sessions active during each hour.
; with SampleWindows as (  
  select 1 as SampleWindowId, @Start as WindowStart, @Start + @Interval as WindowEnd  
  union all  
  select SW.SampleWindowId + 1, SW.WindowStart + @Interval, SW.WindowEnd + @Interval  
    from SampleWindows as SW  
    where SW.WindowEnd < @End  
  ),  
  ActiveSessionsDuringWindow as (  
  select SW.SampleWindowId, SW.WindowStart, SW.WindowEnd, S.SessionStart, S.SessionEnd,  
    -- A "pane" is the more restrictive of the window and the session start/end times.  
    case when SW.WindowStart <= S.SessionStart then S.SessionStart else SW.WindowStart end as PaneStart,  
    case when SW.WindowEnd >= S.SessionEnd then S.SessionEnd else SW.WindowEnd end as PaneEnd,
    Row_Number() over ( partition by SW.SampleWindowId order by S.SessionStart ) as SampleId
    from SampleWindows as SW left outer join  
      @Sessions as S on SW.WindowStart <= S.SessionEnd and S.SessionStart < SW.WindowEnd  
  ),  
  ConcurrentSearch as (  
  select SampleWindowId, WindowStart, WindowEnd, SampleId, SessionStart, SessionEnd, PaneStart, PaneEnd,  
    Cast( '|' + Right( Replicate( '0', 3 ) + Cast( SampleId as VarChar(4) ), 4 ) + '|' as VarChar(1024) ) as SampleIds,  
    Cast( case when SampleId is NULL then 0 else 1 end as Int ) as Sessions  
    from ActiveSessionsDuringWindow  
  union all  
  select CS.SampleWindowId, CS.WindowStart, CS.WindowEnd, ASDW.SampleId, CS.SessionStart, CS.SessionEnd,  
    case when CS.PaneStart <= ASDW.PaneStart then ASDW.PaneStart else CS.PaneStart end as PaneStart,  
    case when CS.PaneEnd >= ASDW.PaneEnd then ASDW.PaneEnd else CS.PaneEnd end as PaneEnd,  
    Cast( CS.SampleIds + Right( Replicate( '0', 3 ) + Cast( ASDW.SampleId as VarChar(4) ), 4 ) + '|' as VarChar(1024) ),  
    CS.Sessions + 1  
    from ConcurrentSearch as CS inner join  
      ActiveSessionsDuringWindow as ASDW on ASDW.SampleWindowId = CS.SampleWindowId and  
        -- We haven't visited this session along this path.  
        CS.SampleId < ASDW.SampleId and -- EDIT: Reduce the size of the search tree.  
        CharIndex( '|' + Right( Replicate( '0', 3 ) + Cast( ASDW.SampleId as VarChar(4) ), 4 ) + '|', CS.SampleIds ) = 0 and  
        -- The session's pane overlaps the concurrent search pane.  
        CS.PaneStart <= ASDW.PaneEnd and ASDW.PaneStart <= CS.PaneEnd  
  ) 
  select WindowStart, Max( Sessions ) as Sessions
    from ConcurrentSearch as CS 
    group by WindowStart
```

This should be easy to modify to run against an existing table.  A single index on `SessionStart` ascending, `SessionEnd` ascending should improve performance.

Comment: I've updated the post to include how the data in the data actually looks

Comment: I'm testing this query with the actual data. It looks like that if it's dealing with rows nearing 100 for a given hour, it does not finish executing. Almost like it's in a endless loop. Any ideas?

Comment: In yesterday's I edit corrected the line `CS.SessionId < ASDW.SessionId and -- EDIT: Reduce the size of the search tree`.  In my testing that reduced the size of the search tree by a factor of about 1,000.  Do the rows you are feeding in have a unique identity value?  As noted in the edit, having all of the `SessionIdSeq` values set to `1` will cause problems.

Comment: What I have done is take your table @Sessions and populate it with the actual values from my data. Doing a INSERT INTO .. SELECT... this keeps most of your query intact.

Comment: What's strange to me is that I try to use a permanent table instead of the variable table to hopefully get better performance and I get different results. Max sessions is always either 0 or 1 in this case.

Comment: Added a new version of the query to the end of the answer.  It generates its own id values for the rows.  Try tweaking it to work with your table and check the suggestion re: indexing.