# Concurrent User Dashboard

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I have a table of user access logs to an application. Here is some sample data:

```
userid    |          login          | duration (seconds)
--------------------------------------------------------
1         | 2013-04-30 09:24:07.127 | 21456     
2         | 2013-04-29 09:22:05.023 | 26477     
1         | 2013-04-30 10:24:07.787 | 86543    
2         | 2013-04-30 12:55:55.846 | 32237    
1         | 2013-04-30 08:24:12.347 | 92231
```

My goal is to get a few metrics from this data. I need to capture the min, max, and average concurrent logged in users for the past week. Unless someone has a better idea, I believe to get a meaningful average of concurrent connections, I'm going to need to pick an interval. Please correct me if I'm wrong there. If so, I don't think I should have trouble with that. Its the min and the max that are giving me problems.  I'm trying to do this in sql, but to no avail. The problem is trying to figure how measure the overlap between the connections. Should I pull this out and do it in python. I'll have 100,000+ rows, so it may get a little cumbersome, but I only have to generate the report once a day, so efficiency isn't my greatest concern.

I'm sorry I don't have any sample code, I don't really know how to begin here. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you want to do it for some period(s) then [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428873/avoiding-gaps-in-datetime-intervals-with-cte-and-start-and-end-datetimes/12504291#12504291) may be of help.  Although you could summarize the data for all time, does it really have meaning on a dashboard when it is more than a few years old?

Comment: I only need to capture the data that is a week or newer.

Comment: If you're trying to assess the load on your system, I can't imagine these users are active eventhough they are logged in.

Comment: They get logged out after two hours of idleness. But regardless of whether or not they are active, this is the metric I have been tasked to pull. The above data is fake data, I realize the duration is long, so don't let that throw you off. There are also many more rows. I just put that in to give you an idea of what the data looked like.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that should help.  You will probably have to work to figure out what to do about week boundaries, for instance.

The idea is to break up the data into logins and logouts.  The logout occurs at login + secs seconds after the login, so that is easily calculated.  Each login gets a value of `+1` (adds one to the concurrent user count).  Each logout gets a value of `-1`.

This version of the query uses correlated subqueries to figure out the number of concurrent users and the time to the next event.  In SQL Server 2012, these could be replaced by cumulative sum (`sum() over (partition . .  order by)` and `lead()`.

The final step is calculating the average.  This needs to take into account duration to be accurate.  However, this is not 100% accurate, because it will miss periods at the beginning and end with no logins.  For that, you may need to add fake records with a value of `0` to the events CTE:

```
with d as (
        select 1 as userid, CAST('2013-04-30 09:24:07.127' as datetime) as logint, 21456 as secs union all
        select 2, CAST('2013-04-29 09:22:05.023' as datetime), 26477 union all
        select 1 , CAST('2013-04-30 10:24:07.787' as datetime), 86543 union all
        select 2, CAST('2013-04-30 12:55:55.846' as datetime), 32237 union all
        select 1, CAST('2013-04-30 08:24:12.347' as datetime), 92231
     ),
     events as (
      select logint as thetime, 1 as loginp
      from d
      union all
      select DATEADD(second, secs, logint), -1
      from d
     ),
     t as (
      select e.*,
             (select SUM(loginp) from events e2 where e2.thetime <= e.thetime) as concurrents,
             (select top 1 thetime from events e2 where e2.thetime > e.thetime order by e2.thetime desc) as nexttime,
             DATEDIFF(second, thetime, (select top 1 thetime from events e2 where e2.thetime > e.thetime order by e2.thetime desc)) as dur
      from events e
     )
select SUM(concurrents*1.0*dur)/SUM(dur) as avg_concurrents,
       MIN(concurrents), MAX(concurrents)
from t
```

This assumes that there are no duplicate times -- you have no way of distinguishing between duplicates in the question.  If you have an id, it is easy enough to incorporate that to figure out what happens next, rather than using the time.

Comment: So its a little hard for me to follow some of the logic, but I'm confused why you do `with d as(select......` then you select each row in my sample table. I don't know what is in the table to begin with, so it makes it difficult to insert those values into the query. But also, my table has 100,000+ rows. I don't want to have to select and union all of them. Is that what you're suggesting with you example?

Comment: @Hoopdady - One way to debug, or understand, this type of operation is to replace the last `select` with one that displays the intermediate results.  `select * from d` will display your sample data.  `select * from events` shows it turned into a table of logins (+1) and logouts (-1).  `select * from t` shows the first part of the _then a miracle occurs_ step.